# Allowing multiple polling for user

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

Is there a way to allow user to vote for multiple proposals.
For example:
User A can vote for proposals :P1,P2,P3,etc.
Once A has voted for P1 he should not be allowed to vote for P1 but is eligible to vote for P2 and P3. I am able to write a contract that shows which proposals the candidate has voted for.
Can any one help!!

Comment: Are you talking about Proof of Stake?

Comment: Anything is possible! How this can be achieved depends on your implementation, however. Please enlighten us.

Comment: I am unable to devise a logic for it. can anyone help me with that. I have struct for proposal:

Comment: Oh, I just answered, but forgot to ask if you actually use Solidity.

Comment: Yes. I am using solidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep users' eligibility to vote for a particular proposal in a structure like

```
mapping(uint => mapping(address => bool)) hasVoted;
//      ^proposal IDs   ^users     ^already voted or not
mapping(uint => uint) votesCount;
```

and then check if they are eligible to vote, here's an example in Solidity:

```
modifier canVote(address user, uint proposal){
    require(!hasVoted[proposal][user]);
    _;
}

function vote(uint proposal)
public 
canVote(msg.sender, proposal) //throw if user has already voted
{
    hasVoted[proposal][msg.sender] = true; //make note of the fact he's voting now
    votesCount[proposal]++;
    //other voting logic you need
}
```

Take care to use a suitable type for your proposal IDs, like `uint8` or whatever is enough.

Comment: if i want to check/allow user to vote for candidate in a proposal then i would have to modify my hasVoted mapping right?? mapping(bytes32 => mapping(bytes32 => mapping(address => bool))) hasVoted;. however the user should be able to vote for candidate in other proposal say P2.

Comment: Well, naturally, the code should depend on what you want it to do. This example shows just voting for proposals, i.e. how many votes a proposal collects. If voting structure is more complex than that, it probably means you just have to change `votesCount` structure and its use.  `hasVoted` can stay the same.

Comment: I am sorry to have asked these questions. I am new to programming and solidity

Comment: No probs, questions is what this sites is all about. Clarifying the above: I think you don't have to alter `hasVoted`, because a user can vote for a proposal only once, no matter which candidate he picked ( is that right? )

Comment: I want to allow user to vote for multiple proposals.But only one candidate in each proposal. For example: Proposals:P1(C1,C2) ;P2(C3,C4:candidates). The user should be allowed to vote for P1 and P2 but only one candidate in each. Also if user has voted for candidate in P1, then he should not be allowed to vote for candidate in P1 again

Comment: Yep, for this use case `hasVoted` structure and the modifier in this example stay the same.